# How to get code page of font by using font file name in c++

Tags: fonts, codepages, libharu

I have the font file name. I have to set code page at runtime to get HPDF_Font handle in LibHaru PDF lib. Currently, it is using CP1252 code page. We need support fonts from other code pages.

Code snippet:

```
const char * font_name = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(m_hPdfDoc, ttfFile(), HPDF_TRUE);
HPDF_Font hFont = HPDF_GetFont(m_hPdfDoc, font_name, codePage); //
```

Is there any way to get code page by using font file name? Or is there any other way to get the code page at runtime?

Comment: Other way around: fonts don't care about codepages, they can support more than one (even literally dozens). Figure out which codepages you need to support (and honestly, the true answer here is "none, use unicode, it's not the 80's anymore) and then make sure the fonts you want to use work with those codepages.

Comment: I have to use code128 fonts to print barcodes. But we use "CP1252" with libharu funciton HPDF_GetFont() then it doesn't work but if we use code page "ISO8859-1" then prints the barcode. How can we support this font with Unicode?

Comment: that sounds like information that should be in the question, not just in a comment, because it sounds like the real problem is "we want to use code128 but they don't work unless we use code page XYZ, does anyone know why? here's the (reduced) code we're using: ..." - try to avoid [XY questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)